# Importing Excel into SQL with mixed columns - Large Numbers Contain E+

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql

I'm importing an Excel document into a SQL table via the Import Wizard. My table contains many columns and a few of them contain phone numbers, and number/letter identifiers that are rather long (10+ numbers).

Once the Excel document is imported, these numbers get modified. An example: 22222222222222200000 gets stored as 2.22222E+19 in the SQL database.

I've tried formatting the columns in Excel to be strings, general, integer, and etc. but it doesn't seem to matter. When the columns are set to integer, they show the number accurately in Excel, but upon import, they are modified to contain E+.

While uploading, the Import Wizard automatically assumes these columns are "Float," and I've tried altering them to nvarchar as well. The import will still modify the large numbers.

Is there any way to import these values exactly as they appear in Excel?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You might find it easier, in the end, to output from excel to csv, then import the csv. You'll have more control over the export to csv, and more control over the import into the database (whatever database it is...)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I've considered using a CSV, but I'd like to use an Excel if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue before, it's Excel that is the issue not SSIS. Excel samples the 1st few rows and then infers the data type even if you explicitly set it to text. What you need to do is put this into the Excel file connection string in the SSIS package. This instruction tells Excel that the columns contain mixed data types and hints it to do extra checking before deciding that the column is a numeric type when in fact it's not.

```
;Extended Properties="IMEX=1"
```

It should work with this (in most cases). The safer thing to do is export the Excel data to tab delimited text and use SSIS to import that.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option to edit the mappings of the columns to the data type you choose. it's in one of the last stages of the wizard. be careful not to loose the 0 at the beginning of phone numbers due to data transformation, this can sometime be a real headache when you miss it

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having problems, put an apostrophe in front of the text when typing the info into Excel (or programatically add it).  Excel will always identify the value as a string value.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this problem that worked for me was to create a new column in excel and put in the formula =""&CellAddressHavingEPlusValue&"", this will remove E+ from the data. Now you can import the excel and the value loaded from this new column will be proper without E+ in it, the one which had E+ value can be dropped now from the table.